# I have a button that is created from custom button and link that will open a vf page, i want to resize its width and height?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

i am trying to add style class but its not working...here is my code

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="MarkRenewalLostController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" pageStyle= "pageclass"  docType="html-5.0">
<style type="text/css">
.pageclass{
border-width: 8px;
 width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

please suggest some answer.

Comment: vf page ..that is open when click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

No need any css class for that, You can use configuration option its self.

- Create new custom button as i show in image.
- On button click execute the java-script **window.open**
- **window.open** allow you to set your visual page Url, height, width and target page.

> **window.open('/apex/vf191023', '_blank', 'width=800, height=800');**

[image]